# ¿Cómo calcular columnas necesarias para vistas horizontal o vertical en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una app que en un `RecycleView` dentro de un `Fragment` lo uso para mostrar elementos con el siguiente aspecto:

```
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
```

Mi intención es que cuando el usuario rote el dispositivo, tanto como si es Smartphone o Tableta, que se muestre (2 columnas) "eso lo tengo"

```
AAAAAA BBBBB
CCCCCC DDDDD
```

En caso de disponer de más ancho de pantalla, es decir si se visualiza en una tableta, hay más espacio para visualizar elementos, independientemene si está en vertical o horizontal, se debe ajustar a lo más apropiado para la vista. (3 columnas vertical o 5 horizontal etc...)

```
AAAAA BBBBBB CCCCC
DDDDD
```

Partiendo de un mínimo de cada elemento unos 320dp, mi primera intención era utilizar archivos XML lan-w600 etc... y especificar un número fijo de total de columnas en cada uno de ellos.

Pero se me ha ocurrido que puede ser mejor hacerlo dinámicamente dentro de Java, es decir *Obtener el ancho de pantalla independiente si está en vertical o horizontal y dividir por 320* (que es lo que ocupa un elemento) y el resultado seria las columnas apropiadas para mostrase y asignarlo al `GridLayoutManager` del `Recycleview`.

Ahora tengo lo siguiente: solo detecto si esta en horizontal para así mostrase en 2 columnas.

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
} else {
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()); //fix
}
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por experiencia propia te comento que es mejor realizarlo programáticamente ya que tienes mejor control de los valores para calcular el número de elementos y el mantenimiento puede ser más rápido, la consideración a tomar es el ancho del dispositivo en pixeles ya sea en horizontal y vertical y teniendo como base una medida de tu contenedor, por ejemplo teniendo un contenedor de 300 pixeles de ancho, tenemos:

```
int medidaContenedor = 300; // 300 pixeles
int numColumnas = 0;
numColumnas = obtieneAnchoDispositivo(context)/medidaContenedor;
```

- Cuando mi dispositivo esta en modo `vertical` mide 1080 pixeles de ancho y resultan 3 columnas.
- Cuando mi dispositivo esta en modo `horizontal` mide 1920 pixeles de ancho y resultan 6 columnas.

un método para obtener el ancho del dispotivo independientemente de la orientación:

```
public static int  obtieneAnchoDispositivo(Context mContext){
        int width = 0;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1){
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
        }else{
            width = display.getWidth();
        }
        return width;
    }
```

En este ejemplo se realizan los calculos en pixeles ya que se puede pensar que en una Tablet siempre caben más elementos, pero algo importante a considerar es la resolución, en ocasiones podemos encontrar teléfonos con aún más resolución que tabletas.

> En realidad no existe un calculo exacto para definir cuantas columnas
>   de elementos puedes tener, eso lo determina el requerimiento de tu
>   aplicación, la mayoría de las aplicaciones `iOS` y `Android` tienen un
>   limite de elementos a mostrar dependiendo de la orientación.

Answer (score 1):

Dejo mi solución, si la resolución es menor de 640 y se pone en horizontal se atribuye siempre 2 columnas y para resoluciones mayores, se calcula la columnas apropiadas:

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    //int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int columns = (int) Math.round(width / 400);

    if (width <= 640 ) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
        } else {
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        }
    } else {
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),columns);
    }
```